# How do you make a comparative stem and leaf plot in R?

Tags: r, compare

How do you make a comparative stem and leaf plot in R? The data on one side is

```
c(5.9, 7.2, 7.3, 6.3, 8.1, 6.8, 7.0, 7.6, 6.8, 6.5, 7.0, 6.4, 7.9, 9.0,
  8.2, 8.7, 7.8, 9.7, 7.4, 7.7, 9.7, 7.8, 7.7, 11.6, 11.3, 11.8, 10.7)
```

and the data on the other side is

```
c(6.1, 5.8, 7.8, 7.1, 7.2, 9.2, 6.6, 8.3, 7.0, 8.3, 7.8, 8.1, 7.4, 8.5, 
  8.9, 9.8, 9.7, 14.1, 12.6, 11.2)
```

I have already assigned each to either `x[1]` or `x[2]`. I have tried making two stem and leaf plots and then combining them but that does not work.

Comment: How are you defining a "comparative stem and leaf plot"? Do you have a reference or example somewhere? When you said you "tried making two stem and leaf plots and then combining them but that does not work" - what exactly does "does not work" mean? What code did you try? You should include what you tried, the specific problem with your attempt, and an explicit description of the desired output.

Comment: I define it as having 2 sets of data on the same stem and leaf plot but on opposite sides of each other so you are able to compare where each data points fall, the only reference I have would be in the back of my textbook 
http://content.answcdn.com/main/content/img/oxford/Oxford_Statistics/0199541454.stem-and-leaf-diagram.2.jpg  here is an example of what it looks like and the code I tried was a very weak attempt. It was simply stem(x[1],x[2]) because I have never seen any type of code that results in a two sided stem and leaf plot.

Comment: I'm sure you have your reasons for using stem and leaf plot, but I think using [histograms](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html) is a better way of comparing the same information.

Comment: I agree a histrogram is a better way to do it but unfortunately this is what the book asks for since it is my homework hahaha

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [`stem.leaf.backback`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/aplpack/versions/1.3.0/topics/stem.leaf) of the [aplpack](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/aplpack/index.html) package. It sounds like that may be what you are looking for.

```
> a <- c(5.9, 7.2, 7.3, 6.3, 8.1, 6.8, 7.0, 7.6, 6.8, 6.5, 7.0, 6.4, 7.9, 9.0, 8.2, 8.7, 7.8, 9.7, 7.4, 7.7, 9.7, 7.8, 7.7, 11.6, 11.3, 11.8, 10.7)
> b <-c(6.1, 5.8, 7.8, 7.1, 7.2, 9.2, 6.6, 8.3, 7.0, 8.3, 7.8, 8.1, 7.4, 8.5, 8.9, 9.8, 9.7,14.1, 12.6, 11.2)
> stem.leaf.backback(a,b)
_________________________________
  1 | 2: represents 1.2, leaf unit: 0.1 
            a       b        
_________________________________
             |  5* |             
   1        9|  5. |8        1   
   3       43|  6* |1        2   
   6      885|  6. |6        3   
  11    43200|  7* |0124     7   
  (6)  988776|  7. |88       9   
  10       21|  8* |133     (3)  
   8        7|  8. |59       8   
   7        0|  9* |2        6   
   6       77|  9. |78       5   
             | 10* |             
   4        7| 10. |             
   3        3| 11* |2        3   
   2       86| 11. |             
             | 12* |             
_________________________________
                    HI: 12.6     
                    14.1         
n:         27       20       
_________________________________
```

Setting the m parameter to 1 gives:

```
> stem.leaf.backback(a,b,m=1)
___________________________________________
  1 | 2: represents 1.2, leaf unit: 0.1 
                  a      b              
___________________________________________
    1             9|  5 |8             1   
    6         88543|  6 |16            3   
  (11)  98877643200|  7 |012488        9   
   10           721|  8 |13359        (5)  
    7           770|  9 |278           6   
    4             7| 10 |                  
    3           863| 11 |2             3   
                   | 12 |6             2   
___________________________________________
                         HI: 14.1           
n:               27      20             
___________________________________________
```

Comment: link is broken?

Comment: @ChenStatsYu thanks for spotting it. I'll try to find it.

Comment: I guess Microsoft bought Inside-R or something. I added a note to explain. The main functionality is from the `aplpack` package. I added its CRAN link above.

Comment: It seems contents has been moved to the new [RDocumentation site](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/aplpack/versions/1.3.0/topics/stem.leaf). Examples can be run online there.

Comment: @UweBlock thanks for the link. I modified the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The basic `stem` function has no support for this. It would be easier to do a histogram as @pbible pointed out (although, not much easier if you want them back to back). But you could do

```
#sample data
x<-list()
x[[1]]<-c(5.9, 7.2, 7.3, 6.3, 8.1, 6.8, 7.0, 7.6, 6.8, 
    6.5, 7.0, 6.4, 7.9, 9.0, 8.2, 8.7, 7.8, 9.7, 7.4, 7.7, 
    9.7, 7.8, 7.7, 11.6, 11.3, 11.8, 10.7)
x[[2]]<-c(6.1, 5.8, 7.8, 7.1, 7.2, 9.2, 6.6, 8.3, 7.0,
    8.3, 7.8, 8.1, 7.4, 8.5, 8.9, 9.8, 9.7, 14.1, 12.6, 11.2)

#specify common breaks
brx <- pretty(range(unlist(x)), 
    n = nclass.Sturges(unlist(x)),min.n = 1)

#calculate bins
h1 = hist(x[[1]], breaks=brx, plot=FALSE)
h2 = hist(x[[2]], breaks=brx, plot=FALSE)

#draw
plot(NA,NA,type="n", xlab="", ylab="",
    xlim=range(c(-h1$counts, h2$counts)),
    ylim=range(brx),
    xaxt="n"
)

rect(-h1$counts, brx[-1], 0,  brx[-length(brx)], col="blue")
rect(0, brx[-1], h2$counts,  brx[-length(brx)], col="red")

axis(1, at=axTicks(side=1), labels=abs(axTicks(side=1)))
```

which gives you

[image]

And if it really needs to be stem and leaf style, here's a fragile attempt

```
x<-list()
x[[1]]<-c(5.9, 7.2, 7.3, 6.3, 8.1, 6.8, 7.0, 7.6, 6.8, 6.5, 7.0, 6.4, 7.9, 9.0, 8.2, 8.7, 7.8, 9.7, 7.4, 7.7, 9.7, 7.8, 7.7, 11.6, 11.3, 11.8, 10.7)
x[[2]]<-c(6.1, 5.8, 7.8, 7.1, 7.2, 9.2, 6.6, 8.3, 7.0, 8.3, 7.8, 8.1, 7.4, 8.5, 8.9, 9.8, 9.7, 14.1, 12.6, 11.2)

X<-stack(setNames(x, c("a","b")))

brx <- pretty(range(X$values), 
    n = nclass.Sturges(X$values),min.n = 1)

X$stem <- factor(brx[cut(unlist(x), breaks=brx, include.lowest=T, labels=F)], levels=brx[-length(brx)])
X$leaf <- as.integer(X$values %% 1 *10)


max.leaf.width <- 2*with(aggregate(leaf~ind+stem, X, length), tapply(leaf, ind, max))

fmt<-paste0("%", max.leaf.width[1],"s | %2s | %-", max.leaf.width[2],"s")

va<-with(subset(X, ind=="a"), tapply(leaf, stem, function(x) paste(rev(sort(x)), collapse=" ")))
vb<-with(subset(X, ind=="b"), tapply(leaf, stem, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=" ")))

va[is.na(va)]<-""
vb[is.na(vb)]<-""

cat(paste(sprintf(fmt, va, levels(X$stem), vb), collapse="\n"), "\n")
```

Which produces

```
                 9 |  5 | 7         
     7 7 5 4 2 0 0 |  6 | 0 0 5     
 9 7 7 7 7 5 4 2 2 |  7 | 0 2 4 7 7 
           6 1 0 0 |  8 | 0 3 3 5 9 
               6 6 |  9 | 1 6 8     
                 6 | 10 |           
             8 5 3 | 11 | 1         
                   | 12 | 5         
                   | 13 |           
                   | 14 | 0
```